# WPF binding to the same property of multiple objects in a collection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I'm trying to create an interface using WPF that can display and modify the properties of multiple selected objects at once.  I know this must be possible (the property grid in Visual Studio does it) but I haven't been able to find any information or examples on how to achieve it.  I have found a lot of information on MultiBinding, but the canonical use case of that appears to be to bind one UI field to multiple properties on the same object while I'm trying to do the opposite - binding a UI field to the same property on multiple objects.

To be more explicit, the behaviour I want to create is this:

- If a single object is selected, the properties of that object are
  displayed
- If more than one object is selected, properties are displayed according to the following logic:

  - If all selected objects have the same value in that property, display the value
  - If the selected objects have different values in that property, display '[Multi]' (or similar)
- When a value is entered, all selected object have the bound property set to that value.

By way of example, here is an old WinForms form of mine that does the same thing and which I am more-or-less trying to recreate in WPF.  In that case I dealt with it in the code-behind without data binding, an experience I'm not particularly keen to repeat.

With one item selected:

[image]

With several items selected (Element Type, Material and Beta Angle properties the same, others different):

[image]

Some other considerations for my particular use-case:

- Pretty much the whole UI of my application needs to work in this way,
  so the more easily repeatable the better
- The number of selected items could range from 1-100000 (though will more typically be around the order of a few dozen - some slight lag on huge selections is probably OK provided it doesn't become unusable)
- There will be several different types of data I'll want to make editable, each with its own bespoke interface (i.e. I don't actually want a generic Property Grid solution)
- The datatypes I'm binding to are defined in a separate and publically-available library that I (partly) write but that several other people and projects use.  So, I *can* modify those types if I absolutely have to but I'd rather not do anything too drastic to them.

My current best-guess for how to do this would be to use a MultiBinding (or a custom sub-class of it), track changes in the underlying collection and programmatically add or remove bindings to the properties on each object to the MultiBinding Bindings collection, then write an IMultiValueConverter to determine the display value.  However, that seems like a bit of a fiddle, not really what MultiBindings were designed for and internet opinion appears to disfavour using MultiBindings except for where absolutely necessary (although I'm not entirely sure why).  Is there a better/more straightforward/standard way of doing this?

Comment: Sounds easy as for me. Have dedicated property to edit value in ViewModel and handle multi-selection. Then in the setter set value of every selected item. When selection changed you may want to trigger notification of that property, so that getter may provide value to be displayed (not sure which one you want, it can be e.g. average value of all items selected). And yes, look into MVVM if you didn't yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that object encapsulation would really help you here, rather than trying to make MultiBinding do something it's not really equipped to handle.

So, without seeing your code, I'll make a couple of assumptions:

1. You have a `ViewModel` that represents each object.  Let's call this `ObjectViewModel`.
2. You have a top-level `ViewModel` that represents the state of your page.  Let's call this `PageViewModel`.

`ObjectViewModel` might have the following properties:

```
string Name { get; set; }
string ElementType { get; set; }
string SelectionProfile { get; set; }
string Material { get; set; }
... etc
```

and `PageViewModel` might have the following:

```
// Represents a list of selected items
ObjectSelectionViewModel SelectedItems { get; }
```

Notice the new class `ObjectSelectionViewModel`, which would not only represent your selected items, but allow you to bind to it as if it were a single object.  It might look something like this:

```
public class ObjectSelectionViewModel : ObjectViewModel
{
    // The current list of selected items.
    public ObservableCollection<ObjectViewModel> SelectedItems { get; }

    public ObjectSelectionViewModel()
    {
        SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<ObjectViewModel>();
        SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
             // Pseudo-code here
             if (items were added)
             {
                  // Subscribe each to PropertyChanged, using Item_PropertyChanged
             }
             if (items were removed)
             {
                 // Unsubscribe each from PropertyChanged
             }                   
        };
    }

    void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, NotifyPropertyChangedArgs e)
    {
         // Notify that the local, group property (may have) changed.
         NotifyPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get 
        {
            if (SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                 return "[None]";
            }
            if (SelectedItems.IsSameValue(i => i.Name))
            {
                 return SelectedItems[0].Name;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                SelectedItems[0].Name = value;
            }
            // NotifyPropertyChanged for the traditional MVVM ViewModel pattern.
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }           
    }

    public override string SelectionProfile
    {
        get 
        {
            if (SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                 return "[None]";
            }
            if (SelectedItems.IsSameValue(i => i.SelectionProfile)) 
            {
                return SelectedItems[0].SelectionProfile;
            }
            return "[Multi]";
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
            {
                item.SelectionProfile = value;
            }
            // NotifyPropertyChanged for the traditional MVVM ViewModel pattern.
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectionProfile");
        }           
    }

    ... etc ...
}

// Extension method for IEnumerable
public static bool IsSameValue<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, U> selector) 
{
    return list.Select(selector).Distinct().Count() == 1;
}
```

You could even implement `IList<ObjectViewModel>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` on this class to turn it into a full-featured list that you could bind to directly.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it slightly misinterprets the question - I only want to display '[Multi]' if the selected objects do not all have the same value, so simply checking the count of SelectedItems is not good enough, I need to iterate through the collection until I find a different value, and I would need to do that in every getter.  As noted in the question I also have quite a few different types of ObjectViewModel and I would need to write a ObjectSelectionViewModel to wrap the properties of each one, which seems like a disadvantage compared to the MultiBinding option.

Comment: Also, this would not detect property changes in selected objects made outside of the UI (which may happen) - I'd need to subscribe to that event on each selected object and bubble it upwards to capture those changes, which MultiBinding would effectively do for me.

Comment: Edit per your comments.
1.  Added IsSameValue() to handle unique-ness
2.  Different types of ObjectViewModel - what will your UI look like when you select objects of different types?  ViewModels are models-to-a-view, so if your View is changing you'll likely need to either (a) combine your properties to a single place (as demonstrated above) or (b) use a different collection object per type of ObjectViewModel.
3.  Added property change notification for each item added to the list of SelectedItems (pseudo-code).

Note that I didn't have time to compile/test.  This is all theory :)

Comment: For different object types, The #3 answer of @Liero seems worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not in WPF out of the box, however there are some options how to achieve this:

1. Use some 3rd party control, that support edit of multiple objects at once, e.g. [PropertyGrid from Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home)
2. Create wrapper object that has the same properties as your objects but is wraps collection of objects. Then bind to this wrapper class.

   ```
   public class YourClassMultiEditWrapper{
       private ICollection<YourClass> _objectsToEdit;

       public YourClassMultiEditWrapper(ICollection<YourClass> objectsToEdit)
           _objectsToEdit = objectsToEdit;

       public string SomeProperty {
          get { return _objectsToEdit[0].SomeProperty ; } 
          set { foreach(var item in _objectsToEdit) item.SomeProperty = value; }
       }
   }

   public class YourClass {
      public property SomeProperty {get; set;}
   }
   ```

   Advantage is that it is quite simple to do. Disadvantage is that you need to create wrapper for each class you want to edit.

3. You can use custom `TypeDescriptor` to create generic wrapper class. In your custom `TypeDescriptor` override GetProperties() method so it will return the same properties as your objects. You will also need to create custom `PropertyDescriptor` with overridden `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods so it works with your collection of objects to edit

```
    public class MultiEditWrapper<TItem> : CustomTypeDescriptor {
      private ICollection<TItem> _objectsToEdit;
      private MultiEditPropertyDescriptor[] _propertyDescriptors;

      public MultiEditWrapper(ICollection<TItem> objectsToEdit) {
        _objectsToEdit = objectsToEdit;
        _propertyDescriptors = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TItem))
          .Select(p => new MultiEditPropertyDescriptor(objectsToEdit, p))
          .ToArray();  
      }

      public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
      {
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(_propertyDescriptors);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (in ViewModel):

```
ObservableCollection<Item> _selectedItems;
// used to handle multi selection, the easiest is to set it from View in SelectionChanged event
public ObservableCollection<Item> SelectedItems
{
    get { return _selectedItems; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        // this will trigger View updating value from getter
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeProperty));
    }
}

// this will be one of your properties to edit, you'll have to do this for each property you want to edit
public double SomeProperty
{
    get { return SelectedItems.Average(); } // as example
    set
    {
        foreach(var item in SelectedItems)
            item.SomeProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Then just bind `SomeProperty` to whatever have to display/edit its value and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make bindings work the way you want them to out of the box.  But you can make the PropertyChanged event work in your favor by handling it in a wrapper class of items of your type.  In the code below The MultiEditable class handles the PropertyChanged event for the EditItem property.  If you have a form where users are editing properties of, say, a beam you will want to bind input controls on the form to properties of EditItem.  You will need to override _EditItem_PropertyChanged as shown and from there you can update properties of selected items as properties of EditItem are changed.  Don't forget to un-handle events.

Edit:  I forgot to add code for checking if all properties are the same as some value.  That is easy enough to do - just check the collection and compare the property in question for all items against the same property of EditItem.  If they are all the same return true, otherwise "Multi" or whatever you need.  Also you can reference MultiEditable in your code - just update EditItem properties and selected items and visuals will all be updated.

```
public interface ISelectable
{
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MultiEditable<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T:class,ISelectable,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T _EditItem;
    public T EditItem 
    {
        get { return _EditItem; }
        set 
        { 
            if(_EditItem != value)
            {
                _EditItem = value;
                _EditItem.PropertyChanged += _EditItem_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool AreMultipleItemsSelected
    {
        get { return this.Count(x => x.IsSelected) > 1; }
    }

    public virtual void _EditItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class MultiEditableBeams : MultiEditable<Beam> 
{
    public override void _EditItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base._EditItem_PropertyChanged(sender, e);

        foreach (Beam beam in this.Where(x => x.IsSelected))
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Material")
                beam.Material = EditItem.Material;
            else if (e.PropertyName == "Length")
                beam.Length = EditItem.Length;

        }
    }
}

public class Beam : ISelectable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected 
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsSelected != value)
            {
                _IsSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Material;
    public string Material
    {
        get { return _Material; }
        set
        {
            if (_Material != value)
            {
                Material = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private int _Length;
    public int Length
    {
        get { return _Length; }
        set
        {
            if (_Length != value)
            {
                _Length = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```